# Move all to https or keep both?

Tags: node.js, https

I have a rest api written in node js that serves my Ember app;

This api creates a http server; recently I've added a second server (https) for handling the login process;

```
//server start
App.listen(process.env.PORT || configuration.server.port, function() {
    console.log("server is listening on port: " + configuration.server.port);
});

//secure server start
var server = https.createServer(options, SecureApp).listen(configuration.secureServer.port, function() {
    console.log("secure server is listening on port: " + configuration.secureServer.port);
});
```

The normal server is used to exchange data published by the Ember app that does not need protection, the secure server is used for the login (sending password etc...).
Now the question: does it makes sense to keep both the servers or should I move everything to the secure server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep both no doubt about that. Even if you like to switch one or the other you can do it using a custom middle-wire or redirect to http/https by

```
      res.statusCode = 302;
      res.setHeader('Location', 'https://' + req.headers['host'] +  (('/' !== req.url) ? '/' + req.url : ''));
      res.end();
```

In my case, I have kept both but for production i have forced every request to https. Obviously development environment has support for both http and https.